# Does any group resampling function / library for imbalanced data?

Tags: python, pandas, model, prediction, resampling

I am creating a generic model to make a prediction. The training dataset comes from different sources with hourly, and it occurred the imbalanced dataset issue.

Therefore, I would like to group the site and hour to resample the data to have a near/equal number of data row. (i.e. groupby(["site", "hourly"]) -> to do resample)

```
My df:
y  source  hour x1  x2
1    A      0   10  20
20   A      1   32  14
...
32   B      0   32  10
...
```

```
df[['source', 'hour']].groupby(['source', 'hour']).count()

Source   Hour    Count
A          0    25.0    
A          1    36.0    
A          2    38.0    
     ...
A          9    37.0    
A          10   164.0   
A          11   227.0   
     ...
A          16   252.0   
A          17   249.0   
B          0    288.0   
B          1    298.0   
B          2    304.0
     ...
B          7    295.0   
B          8    298.0
B          9    308.0
     ...
```

Does any function/library can let me easier to over/under resampling on the grouped data?

I  have researched the `imblearn` library, but it seems for the classification use case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A bit puzzled here, can you give more information on your predictors and predicted value? And if this is not a classification problem as you implied, why would you need resampling for in the first place?

Comment: @nimbous since hour variable is the dummy variable(i.e using the one-hot method) e.g.[0, 0 ,... ,1], and different data sources(i.e. A, B) have a different scale value on the Y(target value).  As I need to create the generic model to make predictions, imbalanced of sources data and hour data would have an effect on the ANN algorithm. Therefore, I need to try the resampling method to improve the result

Comment: solved, using the df.groupby(['source', 'hour']).apply(lambda x:x.sample(frac = 0.3))